# Survey Monkey API Questions

Tags: surveymonkey

I have a couple questions regarding the survey monkey API. First, I've noticed that the categories that can be assigned to open ended questions don't come through when pulling the details of a response. Is there a way to do this and if not, when will it be added?

Secondly, I've attempting to update the metadata field of a response, yet I'm receiving an invalid schema era.

I'm sending this in the request body:

```
{
  "id": "4472927205",
  "metadata": { "category" : "test"
  }
}
```

This is the response I receive:

```
{
  "error": {
    "http_status_code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid schema in the body provided.",
    "id": "1002",
    "docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes",
    "name": "Bad Request"
  }
}
```

What is the proper schema for a request?

Comment: Their API docs may be more helpful, more quickly than us. https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/

Answer (score 1):

Categories set in the analyze section are not currently accessible through the API. There is no ETA for that at the moment.

Also the metadata shown in the responses are auto-generated based on other factors (some page logic I believe, contact information - case email collector) and are not updateable at the moment either.

See the [docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3) also you can watch the [public docs repo](https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/public_api_docs) to be notified when the changes you'd like have been released.

Answer (score 0):

I've been the same situation. And I figured out that some of my data is null, like:
{
"first_name": null,
"last_name": "",
"email": ""
}

And if you add some data to that null value, no more problems.
I don't know if it can helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).